# rsync how include all folder inside a folder

Tags: linux, rsync

I've read dozens of other answers for this but none of them are working.

**Situation:**

I have a folder and inside it, more folden. I will with **rsync** send it, from a computer to a remote computer. When I to try this

```
sudo rsync -z /home/Downloads/file mine@19x.xxx.xxx.xx:/home/mine
```

and to come this Warning:

> mine@19x.xxx.1xx.xx's password:
>
> Permission denied, please try again.
>
> mine@19x.xxx.1xx.xx's password:
>
> skipping directory Vasco

When try with another folder **without** inside more folder, I can send it..

How to show the folder;

[How to show the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLjb1.png)

Can Please anyone help me, Thanks!

Comment: To answer the title of this question: `-r, --recursive             recurse into directories`. I'm not sure what the rest of the question is about, other than possibly an authentication issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks **Smock**! , that is the solution.

> -r, --recursive recurse into directorie

Now with the command;

```
sudo rsync -r -z /home/Downloads/file mine@19x.xxx.xxx.xx:/home/mine
```

@Smock

> what the rest of the question is about, other than possibly an authentication issue...

The rest which has I to write for First time, was a mistake...

I wish your a nice Day!

Comment: i use normally rsync -av where a includes alot of more